# How to preset the values of radio button when editing a row(struct framework in java)?

Tags: java, html, frameworks, radio-button

I have a registration form with gender selection field.when i register  the value of selected radio button(gender) will store in table. When I try to edit each row I want to preselect the radio button(gender) based on the value in database in edit page and also want to pass the changed gender value to action page in order to update table. checked="checked" attribute is not working when using struct framework. I'am new in struct framework. Please help.

[image]

[image]